# MIPS and MARS bitmap, loading images?

Tags: image-processing, bitmap, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

Is it possible to load images directly to be displayed on MARS bitmap displayer? It seems as if more complex file specifications like .jpeg and .png would be a no go but what about .BMP files? Is it as simple as loading the file into a buffer and displaying it how I would normally using base address for display?

*After looking up the BMP spec I realize the spec is still pretty complicated so I guess the question is more along the lines of if I just grab the pixel array from the .BPM file how will it be affected without the other components?*

Comment: That would depend entirely on the format of that particular BMP file. The MARS bitmap display uses 32-bit pixels, with alpha ignore (AFAIK). The BMP format supports many different pixel formats. For example, a 256-color BMP would use 1 byte per pixel which references a color lookup table stored elsewhere in the file. A 24-bit BMP would have its pixels stored in groups of 3 bytes, with alpha completely omitted.

Comment: @Dustin.Shropshire If you just want to display some bitmaps and don't mind converting them first to another format, I suggest you use [PPM file format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) which is easy to decode

Comment: @gusbro Thanks, Ill give that a look!